# application folder not showing up on sys.path [Python]

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, virtualenv

I have a web application that I am developing on my local machine. I copy over the files to my server, and now my program will not run.

I examined the sys.path on both machines and on my server (where the code wont run) i am missing the top-level directory from my path. I am using virtualenvs on both machines. See the structure below

```
myapplication/
  code/
    main.py
    db.py
  app/
    models.py
```

On my home machine, when I call `$ python2.7 main.py`, everything works fine. I also see that `myapplication/` is on my path, as is `myapplication/app/` (`print sys.path` from within `db.py`)

On the server, I am getting an import error `ImportError: No module named app.models`

The import line in `db.py` is `from app import models`

Looking at the output of `print sys.path` on the server shows that the top level `myapplication/` is missing from the path (only `myapplication/code`)

I have tried deleting and resyncing all of the `__init__.py` files and deleting all of the `*.pyc` files

Any suggestions on why the top-level directory is getting omitted?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the reason for the missing path in server. But what you can do is, add the root directory in system path.

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

In your main.py